# Beaglebone : Save serial data coming through pins onto the memory

Tags: serial-port, beagleboard

I am trying to save the data received onto the memory card and I need some pointers to that since I am completely new to this. 
I configured the mux modes of UART1 and UART2 to act as recievers. Right now what I am doing is using minicom to monitor the data received from those pins. I just run the minicom application on board and the board is connected to computer via USB. The serial data received through pins is being displayed on the screen. 
Instead I want to just store the serial data obtained through pins onto the memory of beaglebone. Can anyone please give me pointers on how to do that? 
If I want to store the data as a text file how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using minicom, then I expect that you can just pipe the serial device to a file as follows:

```
cat /dev/ttyS0 > uart1.dat
cat /dev/ttyS1 > uart2.dat
```